# I'm looking for military discharge rates, the more focused the better

Tags: data-request, usa, military

I'm looking for rates of military discharges by type - honorable, dishonorable, Other Than Honorable, Bad Behavior, Officer, ETC. It would be really, really awesome if I could find this information by veteran's living in state or city, specifically Chicago, Illinois. But just finding military discharge rates nationwide would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this area, but I was told about this site:

http://www.va.gov/VETDATA/Veteran_Population.asp

Which has some data on veteran populations in the U.S. I'm not sure if it has discharge rates, but it might be a good place to start. You could try emailing some of the contact folks referenced in the datasets on that VA site, as they might have a better idea.

Comment: You may also want to look at the Current Population Survey (CPS) Veteran's Supplement. The survey is a joint effort by the US Census and BLS. I can't seem to find a direct link to a dataset (except for Universities which require a subscription), so you may be stuck using data.gov's DataFerret.